# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'polyfillWrapFlushCallback' of null

Tags: javascript

For today the above error message has arrived in my devTools console. This is a method called in the custom-elements-es5-adapter.js
I didn't install any new extension, so I have no idea what could be is this.

Any idea on this issue?

Comment: Without code to look at, we can only guess. Since this is part of web components, it would be handy to have already known that. The error means that the script expects an object with a method named polyfillWrapFlushCallback. Without knowing when and how and why this is called by your code, the only answer we can give is 42.

Comment: @Shilly Thank you for your answer. The mentioned error message is not related to any part of code, it still arrives to me on almost every pages. So I thought it is a common problem.

Comment: Are you using polymer framework? Is this only on IE11 or on all the browsers? How do you bundle everything? How long since the libraries were updated to a new version? What changed between the previous version of your app that did not have the error and now? These are the first questions I would ask by reading the articles google gives me after pasting the error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your current browser (or browser extensions), project/framework etc.,  this might not be spot on for you. In my case I'm working on a vuejs (`"vue": "^2.6.0"`, from `package.json`) project. I am using Chrome as my default browser.

Suddenly, I got this particular error (`Cannot read property 'polyfillWrapFlushCallback' of null`) in inspector without changing anything important in my source code.

When hovering over the error, I got a clue:
[image]

Note the `chrome-extension://aggiicla...`

I checked my current extensions (type `chrome://extensions/` in the address field) and found one with an id starting `aggiicla`

[image]

## Solution

I turned off the extension and reloaded my vuejs application. The error was gone (which is enough for me).

Comment: Thanks, you are absolutely right! Thanks for your solution! Yes, it is!